# OCaml: Automate custom pretty-printer installing

Tags: ocaml

I have implemented a pretty-printer for a module. Currently I start up `utop`, load the dependencies then do `#install_printer pp_custom;;` where `pp_custom` is the pretty-printer.

I would like to automate this so that I can have it in a way that is similar to the `lacaml` library where the pretty-printer for the matrix is "installed" by default.

How would I go about to doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you need to run `#install_printer` directive whenever you load your library in the top. I'm using the following code to evaluate code in the toplevel:

```
open Core_kernel.Std
open Or_error

let eval_exn str =
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string str in
  let phrase = !Toploop.parse_toplevel_phrase lexbuf in
  Toploop.execute_phrase false Format.err_formatter phrase

let eval str = try_with (fun () -> eval_exn str)
```

It depends on `Core_kernel`, but you can get rid of this easily, by just using `eval_exn` instead of `eval` (the last one wraps a possible exception into the `Or_error` monad). Once you've got the `eval` function, it can be used to load your printers:

```
 let () = eval (sprintf "#install_printer %s;;" printer)
```

where `printer` is the name of the pretty printing function (usually qualified with a module name). Usually, one put such code into the separate library, named `library.top`, where `library` is the name of your library.

For further automation, you can require all types, that you want to be auto-printable in toplevel, to register itself in a central registry, and then call all registered printers, instead of enumerating them by hand. To see all this working at once, you can take a look at the [BAP library](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap). It has a sublibrary called `bap.top` that automatically installs all printers. Each type that is desired to be printable implements `Printable` signature, using [`Printable.Make`](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/bap_types/bap_regular.ml#L19) functor, that not only derives many printing functions from the basic definition, but also registers the generated pretty-printers in Core_kernel's `Pretty_printer` registry (you can use your own registry, this is just a set of strings, nothing more). When `bap.top` library is loaded into the toplevel (using `require` or `load` directive), it enumerates all registered printers and [install](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/bap/bap_install_printers.ml) them.

Comment: So I just tried running this code with `corebuild` and I got an unbound module error for `Toploop`. Are there some other commands that I need to pass to `corebuild` for it to include `Toploop`?

Also I'm curious as to why I can access `Toploop.execute_phrase` from `utop` even though it doesn't appear in the list possibilities at the bottom.

Comment: sorry, forget to mention the main part, this `Toploop` comes from `compiler-libs` package, that is shipped with OCaml under QPL License. You need to pass `-pkg compiler-libs` to `corebuild` to get access to it.

Comment: Sorry to repeatedly bother you with this but I am now getting `Error: No implementations provided for the following modules: Toploop referenced from io.cmx`. Along the way `findlib` claims that `Interface topdirs.cmi occurs in several directories: /root/.opam/4.01.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs, /root/.opam/4.01.0/lib/ocaml`. I'm not sure if the error and the warning are somehow related. I have checked `/root.opam/4.0.1.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs` and I do see `toploop.cmi` in it.

Comment: Don't be bothered with this warning, it is  known issue, and it shouldn't affect the result. What concerning `No implementation` problem, you should provide `-pkg compiler-libs` to the `corebuild`, when you're compiling your library, like: `corebuild -pkg compiler-libs yourlibrary.cma`